# DC-DC boost regulator selection question (TPS61230A)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, component-selection, buck-boost

I am a product designer self-learning electrical engineering, not an electrical engineer.
In trying to design a wearable device, I've run into some difficulty in selecting a DC-DC boost regulator.
The [TPS61230A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61230a.pdf) seems to be a good option for regulating the full normal 3.0-4.2V battery range to the needed 3.3V.
From what I've read on the datasheet, it appears to be a good fit for the 2A pulse peak and 500mA cont. draw at 3.3V.
If anyone is willing to verify that I did not misread the specifications and value ranges wrong, or suggestions if a better part exists, it would be appreciated.
Thank you, and have a great weekend.

Comment: The part is a boost regulator and you are asking for output voltage both above and below input voltage. Buck-boost regulators exist if you can’t change that requirement.

Comment: You're asking for a buck (step down) regulator most likely. You won't be able to go down to 3.0, but a battery hardly stores any power below 3.3v anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That device will not work. You can however get a buck-boost or "flying inductor" converter, or use a boost/flyback type regulator in a SEPIC configuration which behaves similarly [to boost] but has an output range above or below the input.

Alternately, if not much current is required, just use an LDO, and either raise the minimum input voltage (you aren't losing much charge capacity in Li-ion this way) or lower the minimum output voltage (most 3.3V devices will be comfortable at 3.0, maybe even 2.7V or less).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option. I just picked any boost PWM that is not "sys".
Change the coil out to a transformer.  In this case 1:1 turn ration.  "coupled inductor" Coilcraft for an example.  Watch the phasing.
The voltage at the switch is 0 and (Vin + Vout).  The voltage on the other winding is Vout.

[image: Adapted diagram from ADP1614 datasheet]

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adp1614.pdf

The supply must both buck and boost. This is a simple way of getting an output voltage that can be above or below the input. The TPS61230A has an internal diode and does not work well with this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The TSP61230A is a boost regulator.  It increases the voltage.
It will take the 3.0 from the battery and make 5V but it will not take the 4.2V and make 3.3V.  If you board ran from 5V and the battery was 3.0 to 4.2 this is a good choice.

Because the battery is both above and below the output volage you need a buck-boost PWM.